# FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, formatexception

The exception is always thrown at the following statement..:

```
    protected void DataList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
x= should get the primary key of the item selected from  a datalist
        Server.Transfer("AnswerQuestion.aspx?x=" + int.Parse(DataList2.DataKeyField) + "&question=" +"bla bla") + "&time=" + DateTime.Now);
    }
```

It throws exception here..:( even when i seperate it
  int threadID = int.Parse(DataList1.DataKeyField.ToString());
Why?

Comment: where exaclty, it could be either Parse or SelectedValue is null.

Comment: The x parameter of the string worries me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I strongly suspect it was this call:

```
int.Parse(DataList2.DataKeyField)
```

That suggests `DataList2.DataKeyField` isn't a valid string representation of an integer in the current locale. (As an aside, you should *probably* be doing this formatting and possibly parsing using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Only user input should be treated using the user's culture.)

Comment: int threadID = int.Parse(DataList1.DataKeyField.ToString());//Exception...how can i correct this

Comment: @Matrix001: Fix your data! Seriously, we have no idea where this data has come from, but you clearly can't parse it as an integer. Why did you think you should be able to? Have you looked to find out what the *actual* value is?

Comment: Datakeyfield  is the fields to be returned in a datakey for the selected row. Typically used to identify primary key values.. I think it is a collection or something.. i am trying to get a primary key out of it

Comment: @Matrix001: You *think* is a collection or something? Surely you should know what your own keys are... but it sounds like they're not string representations of integers. Don't just guess - find out for sure. We can't help you do that.

Comment: I am trying to get the primary keys. By what I am reading now, they are inside DataKeys collection. But I need to find an index of the datalist when i select a specific row, then need to pass it to the collection ..e.g. DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex]. problem is that the eventhandling method doesnt have that parameter in its eventargs..see code updated above

Comment: @Matrix001: Why do you need to find the index? It's pretty unclear what's going on inside your code to be honest, but I think it's irrelevant to your actual question here, which was why your code was throwing an exception. I think I've answered that fairly clearly: you're trying to convert the string to an integer, and it's just *not* an integer. If you want to discuss your broader problem, I suggest you start a new question for that, after reading http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Good suggestion..i will try to resolve it myself. if i cant i will open a new question

Answer (score 1):

Because 'DataList2.DataKeyField' most likely isnt parseable, and not in the correct format.

Comment: But even if i replace that DataList2.DataKeyField.toString.. it goes here    ThreadID = int.Parse(this.Request["x"]); and tells me that string input wasnt in the correct format :(

Answer (score 1):

Server.Transfer does not support query string, it is not a page request, it is just transfer of control to another page. Store data you want to pass to another page in `Context.Items['x']=yourVal` and use them on another page.

Comment: How do i incorporate the items to the string ?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/avi_sanjay/Server.Transfer.htm06172006162238PM/Server.Transfer.htm.aspx http://steveorr.net/faq/passvalues.aspx Read these articles.